# Chrome Extension JS popup is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome-extension

I'm not really sure where to go from here.
Making a chrome extension for the first time.

Here is my manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Get Offensive Wallpapers",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
  "content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "popup.js", "jquery.min.js" ]
    } ]
}
```

Everything else is here in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XM77B/3/

When I load the package, I get the icon next to the omnibox, but when I click on it, I just get a blank screen. Anyone can maybe point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: -1 Code in a fiddle **must** be included in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a couple things that might be wrong:

1. You are missing the `matches` attribute for content scripts (in your manifest JSON file). I set this to `["http://*/*","https://*/*"]`
2. You are not creating the popup correctly. The content scripts in your manifest file (`popup.js` and `jquery.min.js`), are *injected into the actual web pages* that a user visits. They do not get inserted into `popup.html`. You need to have `<script>` tags in `popup.html` to include those JS files (if this is what you intended). You will need to use one of the chrome extension API's messaging protocols to communicate between a content script (the code that gets injected into each page) and your popup (the stuff that shows up when you click the toolbar button).